# Binding nodejs callback result to global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, callback

I'm trying to simplify my node js functions. I'm writing a nightwatch test and this is how my setup looks like.

---

test.js

```
setUp: function(browser, callback) {
var testSetup = function(cb) {
  util.createDefaultSetup(cb);
};

var helper = function(res, cb) {
  // res is the result object from the util function
  default_setup = res.data;
  cb();
};

async.waterfall([
  testSetup,
  helper
], callback);
```

},

---

util.js

```
createDefaultSetup: function(cb) {
console.log('Default Setup');
var args = {};
post(
    URL + '/testing/create_sample_setup/',
    args,
    'Creating ',
    'Not able to create ',
    cb,
    'json');
```

}

This is a working piece of code. I'm trying to make my test.js simpler without async waterfall. Any recommendations? My ultimate motive of test.js function is to bind the callback result(res) and store it in a global variable.

Comment: Why are you using a global `default_setup` variable instead of passing your async results as callback arguments?

Comment: I m just using the global delfault_setup later in the code.

Comment: But how does it "later" know that the variable has been assigned? Only through the callback, that it's available from then on - and when your code is placed in the callback anyway, it's better to avoid globals and use a parameter right away.